# Get element from List<Object>

Tags: java, list

I want to use the variables of `Object`s in a `List<Object>`.

Example: I have the `Student` class

```
public class Student {

    private int dni;
    private String name,

     ..getters and setter..
}
```

and I have a list of student that is already filled. Example: `List<Student>`

My questions is, how can I get the `dni` and `name` of a `Student`?

Comment: Plenty, bit it might help if you actually took the time to consult the JavaDocs and Collections tutorial, wch would have answered your question

Comment: Quick reference: [`List.get(int index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

```
list.get(1).getDNI();
list.get(1).getName();
```

This is what you want I think from your question. Just access the object of the list you want then access the getter method of that object.

Comment: You might want to do zero or else OP would say it give ArrayOutOfBounds Exception.

Comment: Just giving him an example 1 is arbitrary if you read the text i put with it i said "Just access the object of the list you want" this is letting him know that 1 is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the properties of any `Student` in your list by retrieving it with an index and then getting the properties.

Example:

```
Student first = list.get(0);
System.out.println(first.getName() + ": " + first.getDNI());
Student last = list.get(list.size() - 1);
System.out.println(last.getName() + ": " + last.getDNI());
```

If you want to operate on **every** `Student` in your list, you can loop with a *for each*:

```
for(Student student : list) {
    System.out.println(student.getName() + ": " + student.getDNI());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The List Collection supports random access by using the GET method.
To get the first "object", you can use

```
list.get(0);
```

And as brso05 mentioned, you need a getter method.
I know you can have a kind of ArrayAccess, like list.get(0)[0], but I am not sure if it works in this case.